# How to resolve 1020 error in node js request

Tags: node.js, graphql, cloudflare

I am using node js fetch, to **scrape** graphql api content. But website has now used cloudflare to protect themselves. Is there anyway I can bypass cloudflare.

sample request:-

````
                credentials: "same-origin",

                "headers": {
                    "accept": "*/*",
                    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                    "content-type": "application/json",
                    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"92\", \" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"92\"",
                    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
                    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
                    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
                    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
                    "x-api-key": "2f6f419a083c46de9d83ce3dbe7db601",
                    "x-build-id": "ZYBX3lrvsE1If7r197bQQ",
                    "X-Requested-With":"",
                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
                   "cookie":""

                  },
                  "Origin":"https://opensea.io/",
                  "referrer": "https://opensea.io/",
                  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin",
                "body": `{"id":"AssetSearchQuery","query":"query AssetSearchQuery(\\n  $categories: [CollectionSlug!]\\n  $chains: [ChainScalar!]\\n  $collection: CollectionSlug\\n  $collectionQuery: String\\n  $collectionSortBy: CollectionSort\\n  $collections: [CollectionSlug!]\\n  $count: Int\\n  $cursor: String\\n  $identity: IdentityInputType\\n  $includeHiddenCollections: Boolean\\n  $numericTraits: [TraitRangeType!]\\n  $paymentAssets: [PaymentAssetSymbol!]\\n  $priceFilter: PriceFilterType\\n  $query: String\\n  $resultModel: SearchResultModel\\n  $showContextMenu: Boolean = false\\n  $shouldShowQuantity: Boolean = false\\n  $sortAscending: Boolean\\n  $sortBy: SearchSortBy\\n  $stringTraits: [TraitInputType!]\\n  $toggles: [SearchToggle!]\\n  $creator: IdentityInputType\\n  $assetOwner: IdentityInputType\\n  $isPrivate: Boolean\\n  $safelistRequestStatuses: [SafelistRequestStatus!]\\n) {\\n  query {\\n    ...AssetSearch_data_2hBjZ1\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetCardContent_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\\n  assetQuantities(first: 18) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        asset {\\n          relayId\\n          ...AssetMedia_asset\\n          id\\n        }\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetCardContent_asset_27d9G3 on AssetType {\\n  relayId\\n  name\\n  ...AssetMedia_asset\\n  assetContract {\\n    address\\n    chain\\n    openseaVersion\\n    id\\n  }\\n  tokenId\\n  collection {\\n    slug\\n    id\\n  }\\n  isDelisted\\n  ...AssetContextMenu_data_3z4lq0 @include(if: $showContextMenu)\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetCardFooter_assetBundle on AssetBundleType {\\n  name\\n  assetCount\\n  assetQuantities(first: 18) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        asset {\\n          collection {\\n            name\\n            relayId\\n            isVerified\\n            id\\n          }\\n          id\\n        }\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n  assetEventData {\\n    lastSale {\\n      unitPriceQuantity {\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n  orderData {\\n    bestBid {\\n      orderType\\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n    bestAsk {\\n      closedAt\\n      orderType\\n      dutchAuctionFinalPrice\\n      openedAt\\n      priceFnEndedAt\\n      quantity\\n      decimals\\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\\n        quantity\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetCardFooter_asset_fdERL on AssetType {\\n  ownedQuantity(identity: $identity) @include(if: $shouldShowQuantity)\\n  name\\n  tokenId\\n  collection {\\n    name\\n    isVerified\\n    id\\n  }\\n  hasUnlockableContent\\n  isDelisted\\n  isFrozen\\n  assetContract {\\n    address\\n    chain\\n    openseaVersion\\n    id\\n  }\\n  assetEventData {\\n    firstTransfer {\\n      timestamp\\n    }\\n    lastSale {\\n      unitPriceQuantity {\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n  decimals\\n  orderData {\\n    bestBid {\\n      orderType\\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n    bestAsk {\\n      closedAt\\n      orderType\\n      dutchAuctionFinalPrice\\n      openedAt\\n      priceFnEndedAt\\n      quantity\\n      decimals\\n      paymentAssetQuantity {\\n        quantity\\n        ...AssetQuantity_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetCardHeader_data on AssetType {\\n  relayId\\n  favoritesCount\\n  isDelisted\\n  isFavorite\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetContextMenu_data_3z4lq0 on AssetType {\\n  ...asset_edit_url\\n  ...itemEvents_data\\n  isDelisted\\n  isEditable {\\n    value\\n    reason\\n  }\\n  isListable\\n  ownership(identity: {}) {\\n    isPrivate\\n    quantity\\n  }\\n  creator {\\n    address\\n    id\\n  }\\n  collection {\\n    isAuthorizedEditor\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetMedia_asset on AssetType {\\n  animationUrl\\n  backgroundColor\\n  collection {\\n    description\\n    displayData {\\n      cardDisplayStyle\\n    }\\n    imageUrl\\n    hidden\\n    name\\n    slug\\n    id\\n  }\\n  description\\n  name\\n  tokenId\\n  imageUrl\\n  isDelisted\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetQuantity_data on AssetQuantityType {\\n  asset {\\n    ...Price_data\\n    id\\n  }\\n  quantity\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetSearchFilter_data_3KTzFc on Query {\\n  ...CollectionFilter_data_2qccfC\\n  collection(collection: $collection) {\\n    numericTraits {\\n      key\\n      value {\\n        max\\n        min\\n      }\\n      ...NumericTraitFilter_data\\n    }\\n    stringTraits {\\n      key\\n      ...StringTraitFilter_data\\n    }\\n    id\\n  }\\n  ...PaymentFilter_data_2YoIWt\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetSearchList_data_3Aax2O on SearchResultType {\\n  asset {\\n    assetContract {\\n      address\\n      chain\\n      id\\n    }\\n    relayId\\n    tokenId\\n    ...AssetSelectionItem_data\\n    ...asset_url\\n    id\\n  }\\n  assetBundle {\\n    relayId\\n    id\\n  }\\n  ...Asset_data_3Aax2O\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetSearch_data_2hBjZ1 on Query {\\n  ...CollectionHeadMetadata_data_2YoIWt\\n  ...AssetSearchFilter_data_3KTzFc\\n  ...SearchPills_data_2Kg4Sq\\n  search(after: $cursor, chains: $chains, categories: $categories, collections: $collections, first: $count, identity: $identity, numericTraits: $numericTraits, paymentAssets: $paymentAssets, priceFilter: $priceFilter, querystring: $query, resultType: $resultModel, sortAscending: $sortAscending, sortBy: $sortBy, stringTraits: $stringTraits, toggles: $toggles, creator: $creator, isPrivate: $isPrivate, safelistRequestStatuses: $safelistRequestStatuses) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        ...AssetSearchList_data_3Aax2O\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      cursor\\n    }\\n    totalCount\\n    pageInfo {\\n      endCursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment AssetSelectionItem_data on AssetType {\\n  backgroundColor\\n  collection {\\n    displayData {\\n      cardDisplayStyle\\n    }\\n    imageUrl\\n    id\\n  }\\n  imageUrl\\n  name\\n  relayId\\n}\\n\\nfragment Asset_data_3Aax2O on SearchResultType {\\n  asset {\\n    assetContract {\\n      chain\\n      id\\n    }\\n    isDelisted\\n    ...AssetCardHeader_data\\n    ...AssetCardContent_asset_27d9G3\\n    ...AssetCardFooter_asset_fdERL\\n    ...AssetMedia_asset\\n    ...asset_url\\n    ...itemEvents_data\\n    id\\n  }\\n  assetBundle {\\n    slug\\n    ...AssetCardContent_assetBundle\\n    ...AssetCardFooter_assetBundle\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment CollectionFilter_data_2qccfC on Query {\\n  selectedCollections: collections(first: 25, collections: $collections, includeHidden: true) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        assetCount\\n        imageUrl\\n        name\\n        slug\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n  collections(assetOwner: $assetOwner, assetCreator: $creator, onlyPrivateAssets: $isPrivate, chains: $chains, first: 100, includeHidden: $includeHiddenCollections, parents: $categories, query: $collectionQuery, sortBy: $collectionSortBy) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        assetCount\\n        imageUrl\\n        name\\n        slug\\n        id\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      cursor\\n    }\\n    pageInfo {\\n      endCursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment CollectionHeadMetadata_data_2YoIWt on Query {\\n  collection(collection: $collection) {\\n    bannerImageUrl\\n    description\\n    imageUrl\\n    name\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment CollectionModalContent_data on CollectionType {\\n  description\\n  imageUrl\\n  name\\n  slug\\n}\\n\\nfragment NumericTraitFilter_data on NumericTraitTypePair {\\n  key\\n  value {\\n    max\\n    min\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment PaymentFilter_data_2YoIWt on Query {\\n  paymentAssets(first: 10) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        symbol\\n        relayId\\n        id\\n        __typename\\n      }\\n      cursor\\n    }\\n    pageInfo {\\n      endCursor\\n      hasNextPage\\n    }\\n  }\\n  PaymentFilter_collection: collection(collection: $collection) {\\n    paymentAssets {\\n      symbol\\n      relayId\\n      id\\n    }\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment Price_data on AssetType {\\n  decimals\\n  imageUrl\\n  symbol\\n  usdSpotPrice\\n  assetContract {\\n    blockExplorerLink\\n    chain\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment SearchPills_data_2Kg4Sq on Query {\\n  selectedCollections: collections(first: 25, collections: $collections, includeHidden: true) {\\n    edges {\\n      node {\\n        imageUrl\\n        name\\n        slug\\n        ...CollectionModalContent_data\\n        id\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment StringTraitFilter_data on StringTraitType {\\n  counts {\\n    count\\n    value\\n  }\\n  key\\n}\\n\\nfragment asset_edit_url on AssetType {\\n  assetContract {\\n    address\\n    chain\\n    id\\n  }\\n  tokenId\\n  collection {\\n    slug\\n    id\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment asset_url on AssetType {\\n  assetContract {\\n    address\\n    chain\\n    id\\n  }\\n  tokenId\\n}\\n\\nfragment itemEvents_data on AssetType {\\n  assetContract {\\n    address\\n    chain\\n    id\\n  }\\n  tokenId\\n}\\n","variables":{"categories":null,"chains":null,"collection":"${item.collection_slug}","collectionQuery":null,"collectionSortBy":"SEVEN_DAY_VOLUME","collections":["${item.collection_slug}"],"count":32,"cursor":null,"identity":null,"includeHiddenCollections":false,"numericTraits":null,"paymentAssets":null,"priceFilter":null,"query":"","resultModel":null,"showContextMenu":false,"shouldShowQuantity":false,"sortAscending":true,"sortBy":"PRICE","stringTraits":null,"toggles":["BUY_NOW"],"creator":null,"assetOwner":null,"isPrivate":null,"safelistRequestStatuses":null}}`,
                "method": "POST",
                "mode": "cors"
            })```
````